# Why does my token persist but i am being logged out?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am authenticating an user using jwt. As i reload the page, my token persists in the application tab, but i am being logged out anyways.

This is my App.jsx

```
    import './App.css'
    import Home from './components/UI/Home'
    import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
    import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
    import Navbar from './components/UI/Navbar'
    import Footer from './components/UI/Footer'
    import Register from './Pages/Register'
    import Login from './Pages/Login'
    import Profile from './Pages/Profile'
    import Dashboard from './Pages/Dashboard'
    import PrivateRoute from './components/Routing/PrivateRoute'
    
    
    
    function App() {
    
      const { isAuthenticated } = useSelector(state => state.auth)
    
      return (
        <>
        <div className='content-container'>
        <Navbar/>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>}/>
            <Route path='/profile' element={<PrivateRoute><Profile/></PrivateRoute>}/>
            <Route path='/register' element={<Register/>}/>
            <Route path="/" element={isAuthenticated ? <Dashboard/> : <Home/>} />
          </Routes>
        <Footer/>
        </div>
        </>
      )
    }
    
    export default App
```

And this is my authSlice.js

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios';
import setAuthToken from '../utils/setAuthToken';

const initialState = {
  access_token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: {},
  isLoading: false,
  error: null,
};

export const loadUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/loadUser',
  async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    setAuthToken(localStorage.token);

    try {
      const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/auth/me');
      return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);

export const registerUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/registerUser',
  async (user, { dispatch, rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Accept: 'application/json',
        },
      };
      const body = JSON.stringify(user);
      const res = await axios.post(
        'http://localhost:8000/api/auth/register',
        body,
        config
      );
      dispatch(loadUser(user));
      console.log(res.data);
      return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data.message);
    }
  }
);

export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/loginUser',
  async ({ email, password }, { dispatch, rejectWithValue }) => {
    const body = { email, password };
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
    };
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        'http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login',
        body,
        config
      );
      localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.access_token);
      dispatch(loadUser(res.data));
      return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data.message);
    }
  }
);

export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    logoutUser: (state) => {
      state.access_token = null;
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
      state.user = null;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(loadUser.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
        state.isAuthenticated = state.access_token ? true : false;
      })
      .addCase(loadUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isAuthenticated = true;
        state.user = action.payload;
        state.error = null;
      })
      .addCase(loadUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isAuthenticated = false;
        state.error = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(registerUser.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(registerUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.access_token = localStorage.setItem(
          'token',
          action.payload.access_token
        );
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isAuthenticated = true;
        state.user = action.payload;
        state.error = null;
      })
      .addCase(registerUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.user = null;
        state.isAuthenticated = false;
        state.error = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(loginUser.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(loginUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.access_token = action.payload.access_token;
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isAuthenticated = true;
        console.log(state.isAuthenticated);
        state.user = action.payload;
        state.error = null;
      })
      .addCase(loginUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.user = null;
        state.isAuthenticated = false;
        state.error = action.payload;
      });
  },
});

export const { logoutUser } = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

I think my issue has to be on how i am managing `isAuthenticated` but i don´t know what the error is.
If it is the inisital value assignment to false which probably is how can i make for me not to require to login again after reloading the page?

Answer (score -1):

you can try changing the following 2 pieces of code:
const { isAuthenticated } = useSelector(state => state.auth) to
const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem('token')